# Use Arduino GSM/GPRS SIM900 to send sensor data to my web service

Tags: web-services, arduino, sensors, gsm, gprs

Thank you in advance. I am beginner in arduino.

My Question is how to send dynamic sensor data (Continuous Readings) to the web server. I tried the below code to setup the GSM/GPRS connection to the server.

I successfully sent some static data which is in the below code. But when I want to include some dynamic data that comes from sensor, I am unable to insert the same in code.

**Present Code:**

gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"xxxx/new.php?sensor1=100\"")

**Required Code:**

gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"xxxx/new.php?sensor1=DYNAMIC VALUE\"")

**ARDUINO CODE USED & TESTED**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial gprsSerial(7, 8);

void setup()
{
  gprsSerial.begin(19200);
  Serial.begin(19200);

  Serial.println("Config SIM900...");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Done!...");
  gprsSerial.flush();
  Serial.flush();

  // attach or detach from GPRS service 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CGATT?");
  delay(100);
  toSerial();


  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();

  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"xxxx\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();

  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();
}


void loop()
{
   // initialize http service
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
   delay(2000); 
   toSerial();

   // set http param value
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://www.oniee.com/new.php?sensor1=100\"");
   delay(2000);
   toSerial();

   // set http action type 0 = GET, 1 = POST, 2 = HEAD
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
   delay(6000);
   toSerial();

   // read server response
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPREAD"); 
   delay(1000);
   toSerial();

   gprsSerial.println("");
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPTERM");
   toSerial();
   delay(300);

   gprsSerial.println("");
   delay(10000);
}

void toSerial()
{
  while(gprsSerial.available()!=0)
  {
    Serial.write(gprsSerial.read());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on where your getting your dynamic data but for this example I'm going to use a digital input on a single pin

```
int readpin = 4;
byte pinValue;

void loop()
{
   // initialize http service
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
   delay(2000); 
   toSerial();

   pinValue = digitalread(readpin);

   // set http param value
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://www.oniee.com/new.php?sensor1="" + pinValue + ""\"");
   delay(2000);
   toSerial();

   ...
```

The number of " might be a little off I don't have a setup to test this on right now, but this basic idea is:

Check the pin (or pins) for value 
 Store the value 
 Include the value in your string

Comment: Great ... if this answered your question don't forget to mark it as the answer ... Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you can concatenate a string and int like that?

Comment: Hi Someone that matters, Thank you, i sent my dynamic values to MySQL database by using your code. but now the thing is, if i tried to send a string with space its not showing in my database. if i send "AandB" then it is displayed. but if i tried like this, "A and B" (A (space)and(space)B) only A is displayed. Please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a newline is required to.actually submit the request, so.change first one to `print`, inject `data`, then continue with the closing quote *then* add the newline.

Assumes your sensor data is in a variable called `data`.

```
// set http param value
gprsSerial.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://www.oniee.com/new.php?sensor1=");
gprsSerial.print(data);
gprsSerial.println("\"");
delay(2000);
toSerial();
```